# Show names from comma seperated values

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a query on article data which contains a mysql column called products. The field contains values like so 2,20,12. Those numbers represent id's of the rows of products associated with the article.

I need to work out how i can display the products under each article without creating duplicates of each result.

```
     $sql5="SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid=$iconcategoryid";
     $db->setQuery($sql5);
     $articles= $db->loadObjectlist();
     foreach($articles as $article){ 

        $product_ideez = $article->products;

        $sql6="SELECT * FROM #__products_products WHERE id IN($product_ideez)";
        $db->setQuery($sql6);
        $products= $db->loadObjectlist();

        foreach ($products as $product) {

        $productArray .= '<span class="badge">'.$product->name.'</span>';

        }



    // my html output is here
    // i am getting duplication on the output of the product names

    echo '<h1>'.$article->title.'</h1>';
    echo '<hr/>';
    echo $productArray; // this works but then is multiplied for each new entry against the first query.

   }
```

I hope my question is clear enough.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXJFk.jpg

Cheers
John

Comment: So you want your result 2 20 12 in an array?

Comment: I want 2 then 20 then 12 to show each product name without duplciating itself. At the moment i am getting. shoe,jacket,pants / shoe,jacket,pants,shoe,jacket,pants/shoe,jacket,pants,shoe,jacket,pants,shoe,jacket,pants,shoe,jacket,pants. Each forward slash represinting a new row from teh first query.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand it. Please provide sample of some rows and how you like to be presented. Of what you say I understand that you like that if for first article the product id's are 1,2,3 , but for second article are 2,3,15 Then you like for first to be shown 1,2,3, but for second one - only 15. Is it what you say?

Comment: @KanchoIliev Thanks for your help. I have added a link to a screen grab to show whats happening. Yes basically i need to have only 3 products for each row. They keep multiplying. And yes each row would have differnt proucts. I just added the same values in each row in phomyadminn sql update to quickly test.

Comment: You've already got the answer from @EugeneLazarchik :)

Comment: @KanchoIliev Eugene gave me part of an answer but it didnt work. Its ok i'll figure it out. I was hoping my question was clear enough but i dont hink it was maybe. Thanks for your time regardless mate ;)

Comment: It has to work - I've added the code with implementation of Eugene's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize $productArray before using. Add this to the very beginning of the first foreach:

```
$productArray = "";
```

Comment: i added that to the top but still no luck. I tried inserting an image to show you a screen grab but no luck. Theres a link to screen grab in my question. Its hows visually what is occurring. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: You haven't add the line on the top, it has to be after first foreach.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$productArray = "";` added right after `foreach($articles as $article){` is gonna fix your problem. The reason your code doesn't work is because variable $productArray keeps its value between loop iterations (since you're just concatenating new product names with `.=` and never clearing the variable for new articles)

Comment: @EugeneLazarchik it worked. I was adding it above the foreach. When you said very beginning i thought you meant before the loop starts sorry. As soon as i added it after the first foreach it corrected the output. Thank you. I dont know how to approach the votes now. Your answer was correct but Kancho's answer was first and he was on the same path as you.

Comment: Do what you think is right, but it looks to me that Kancho Iliev just took my answer and applied it to your code (instead of just saying what to change). He even described that in his comments: `You've already got the answer from @EugeneLazarchik :)` and `It has to work - I've added the code with implementation of Eugene's answer.`

Answer (score 0):

```
      $sql5="SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid=$iconcategoryid";
      $db->setQuery($sql5);
      $articles= $db->loadObjectlist();
      foreach($articles as $article){ 
        $productArray='';
         $product_ideez = $article->products;

         $sql6="SELECT * FROM #__products_products WHERE id IN($product_ideez)";
         $db->setQuery($sql6);
         $products= $db->loadObjectlist();

         foreach ($products as $product) {

         $productArray .= '<span class="badge">'.$product->name.'</span>';

         }



     // my html output is here
     // i am getting duplication on the output of the product names

     echo '<h1>'.$article->title.'</h1>';
     echo '<hr/>';
     echo $productArray; // this works but then is multiplied for each new entry against the first query.

    }
```

Comment: Thank you Kancho, i will try now. But how will the $article->title; loop through?

There can be more than one article and each article contains several products.

Comment: Yes you are right, but because you've missed end of cycle I've done mistake. Wait, I'll corect it.